# How to make code shorter in ReactJs instead of using Switch case

Tags: reactjs

I have code like this to show the statistic of the order of user by month via the chart

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (order.alls.length > 0 || reservation.alls.length > 0) {
      let jan = 0;
      let feb = 0;
      let mar = 0;
      let apr = 0;
      let may = 0;
      let jun = 0;
      let jul = 0;
      let aug = 0;
      let sep = 0;
      let oct = 0;
      let nov = 0;
      let dec = 0;

      order.alls.forEach((ord, idx) => {
        const month = moment.unix(ord.date_order).format('M');

        switch (Number(month)) {
          case 1:
            jan = jan + ord.is_order;
            break;
          case 2:
            feb = feb + ord.is_order;
            break;
          case 3:
            mar = mar + ord.is_order;
            break;
          case 4:
            apr = apr + ord.is_order;
            break;
          case 5:
            may = may + ord.is_order;
            break;
          case 6:
            jun = jun + ord.is_order;
            break;
          case 7:
            jul = jul + ord.is_order;
            break;
          case 8:
            aug = aug + ord.is_order;
            break;
          case 9:
            sep = sep + ord.is_order;
            break;
          case 10:
            oct = oct + ord.is_order;
            break;
          case 11:
            nov = nov + ord.is_order;
            break;
          case 12:
            dec = dec + ord.is_order;
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      });
      let data = [jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec];
      const tempStatics = {
        labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],

        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Order",
            data: data,
            backgroundColor: "#fab1a0",
            borderColor: "#ff7675",
            borderWidth: 1,
          },
        ],
      }
      setStatics(tempStatics)
    }
  }, [order]);
```

As you see above my code is so long, I would like to make it shorter like I can use some for loop or something but I do not now know how to use it in my previous code. And besides that, I still have a statistic of reservation do not show yet, If I create it, it will longer.

Could anyone help me, please? I have just created it, so I do not have many experiences to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `labels` to be defined *outside* the effect hook since they don't change.

```
const labels = [
  "Jan",
  "Feb",
  "Mar",
  "Apr",
  "May",
  "June",
  "July",
  "Aug",
  "Sep",
  "Oct",
  "Nov",
  "Dec"
];
```

Declare your `data` array up front and simplify your `switch` logic by gathering the cases that are similar. You can also just compare the array lengths directly as any non-zero length is considered truthy.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (order.alls.length || reservation.alls.length) {
    const data = new Array(12).fill(0);

    order.alls.forEach((ord, idx) => {
      const month = moment.unix(ord.date_order).format("M");
      const monthKey = Number(month) - 1;

      switch (monthKey) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 9:
        case 10:
          data[monthKey] += ord.is_order;
          break;
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 11:
        case 12:
          data[monthKey] += ord.total;
          break;
        default:
      }
    });
    
    const tempStatics = {
      labels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Order",
          data: data,
          backgroundColor: "#fab1a0",
          borderColor: "#ff7675",
          borderWidth: 1
        }
      ]
    };
    setStatics(tempStatics);
  }
}, [order]);
```

## Edit

I see you updated your code snippet, which simplifies the `forEach` loop quite a bit:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (order.alls.length || reservation.alls.length) {
    const data = new Array(12).fill(0);

    order.alls.forEach((ord, idx) => {
      const month = moment.unix(ord.date_order).format("M");
      data[Number(month) - 1] += ord.is_order;
    });
    
    const tempStatics = {
      labels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Order",
          data: data,
          backgroundColor: "#fab1a0",
          borderColor: "#ff7675",
          borderWidth: 1
        }
      ]
    };
    setStatics(tempStatics);
  }
}, [order]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having the right approach already in this line:
`let data = [jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec];`

I would recommend to use an array from the start and just have at index 0 the January until index 11 with December.

So you can create an empty array by:

```
const data = new Array(12).fill(0)
```

You can add then the numbers by:

```
data[Number(month) - 1] =  data[Number(month) - 1] + ord.total
```

Any reasons that some months do add `ord.is_order` instead of `ord.total`?

Comment: Sorry that my fault, the correct is `ord.is_order ` not `ord. total`. Thank u so much for catch my error